# How can I solve NotFoundHttpException No query results for model on laravel?

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes, laravel-5.4

My code like this :

```
return redirect()->route('camp.don.summary', ['id'=>$dons->id]);
```

If the code executed, it will call route

The route like this :

```
Route::prefix('camp')->group(function(){
    ...
    Route::prefix('don')->group(function(){
        ...
        Route::get('summary/{id}', 'CampController@summary')->name('camp.don.summary');
    });
});
```

Then the route call controller

The controller like this :

```
public function summary($id)
{
    dd($id);
    return view('camp.don.summary.index');
}
```

On the browser, the url seems like this :

http://myapp.dev/camp/don/summary/31

And the content exist error like this :

> (2/2) NotFoundHttpException No query results for model
>   [App\Models\Camp] 31

How can I solve this error?

Seems my process is still wrong

Comment: Is there no one giving the best solution?

Comment: It is possible that there's some problem with the precedence of your routes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have configured explicit [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding)

Check your `RouteServiceProvider` class

Comment: I had checked it. It seems there is no problem. What needs to be checked?